# I am unable to get combo box values

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, extjs, combobox

Here I have my combo box form like this

```
Ext.define('test.view.user.ComboBox', {
extend : 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
alias : 'widget.comboBox',
fieldLabel : 'Employee Id',
hiddenName : 'EmpId',
//url :'test/empIdList',
store : 'EmpIdStore',
valueField : 'value',
displayField : 'text',
triggerAction : 'all',
name:'empId',
editable : false,
allowBlank: false,
//autoSelect:true,
  // forceSelection:true,
listeners : {
    select: function() 
    {
        this.store.load();{
        alert("hello");
        }
    }
}
});
```

I have a store for this

```
Ext.define('test.store.EmpIdStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

itemId:'empIdStore',

reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    data : [['', '']],
fields: ['EmployeeId', 'userId'],
}),
proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    type:'ajax',
url: 'test/empIdList'
})
});
```

Here I am unable to get the values when I clicked on combo box.

I am using Hibernate, Spring MVC and extjs MVC in this application. In my spring controller I have the empIdList method like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/empIdList", method = { RequestMethod.POST , RequestMethod.GET})
public void empIdList(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hitting db");
    String userId="";
    String s=userDao.empIdList(userId);
    System.out.println(s);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(s);
}
```

And I have my implementation method in UserDaoImpl class like this

```
@Override
public String empIdList(String data) 
{
    String id="";
    List<User> lstUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
    lstUsers = hibernateTemplate.loadAll(User.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < lstUsers.size(); i++) {
        id = lstUsers.get(i).getUserId();
        System.out.println(" Employee id "+id);
        User obj=new User();
        obj.setUserId(id);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(obj); 
        System.out.println(json);
    }
    return id; 
}
```

Can anyone please help me for getting the values of combo box?

Comment: i dont understand your problem. but while going through the code i just noticed that URL of store is test/empIdList and in your controller it is only /empIdList. can you be more elaborate on the question. i dont understand from where the combobox will get loaded?

Comment: Actually I am doing one application. In that I need to get the values of employee id from database using combobox

Comment: i think you are returning id on for json. that is why you are not getting any values in extjs. in your empIdList method. that is the issue, as your UserDaoImpl is returning only id and not a json. EXTJS will not understand anything than JSON. so it is not displaying anything. if you find this as useful ,i will post this as an answer to your question

Comment: Did you even attempt to figure out which part of the system works and which doesn't?

Comment: I am unable to get the code@  Kalaiarasan Manimaran .

Comment: first put breakpoints and debug, there are lot of places that you might be getting problem. analyse that DAO is returning back the json to controller. you can use postman https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en for that.

Comment: Also your store id used in the combobox is different from that of the item id of the store. They are case sensitive.if you are debugging with firebug, you will know come to know the errors in EXTJS code

Comment: Even I have changed that store id also I am unable to get@Kalaiarasan Manimaran

Comment: have you checked your controller is giving you proper JSON response?.make use of firebug. you just fetch the value from .json file in your extjs code first, rather than trying from java.  if you can able to load the .json file, it will be very easy to construct the json structure using java.  this is the syntaxt of proxy you can use in your store and load your store with local json file.proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
  } Hope this will be useful

Comment: Yup its giving the proper response like this. {"data":[{"id":1,"userId":"123"},{"id":2,"userId":"4989"}]}  @  Kalaiarasan Manimaran

Comment: change the URL of your proxy from 'test/empIdList' to 'empIdList' as mentioned in your controller

Comment: Thank for all your comments atlast I have got the result

Comment: good. can you post the same how the issue is cleared. you can post as an answer to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the proxy in store I have got the result. Here is my code

```
Ext.define('test.store.EmpIdStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias : 'widget.empIdStore',
autoLoad: false,
fields: ['id', 'userId'],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'test/empIdList',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    }
}
});
```